# Extract text using regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract the text between the word "CHAIRMAN" and the last period "." in the text, including "CHAIRMAN" and ".". I have the following character vector:
    "CHAIRMAN massive amount of text."

"CHAIRMAN" and "." are mentioned several times in the text, and I only want to extract the text between the first time "CHAIRMAN" is used and the last time the period "." is used. I want to use regular expressions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `sub`

```
TEXT = "CHAIRMAN massive amount of text."
sub(".*?(CHAIRMAN.*\\.).*", "\\1", TEXT)
[1] "CHAIRMAN massive amount of text."
```

Comment: @useR You are right. I just read the "between" part.  Changing answer.

Answer (score 2):

`.+` and `.*` both match greedily, so you can just do the following:

```
string = "The CHAIRMAN massive amount of text. CHAIRMAN massive amount of text. This is just a place holder"

stringr::str_extract(string, "CHAIRMAN.+\\.")

# [1] "CHAIRMAN massive amount of text. CHAIRMAN massive amount of text."
```